# Add a way to exclude messages from specific rooms when searching chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, search

Some sites use a chat bot to post all comments made on a given site into a chat room, in order to provide a permanent archive of all comments posted on that site. There are reasons for and against doing so, but that's outside the scope of this question (personally, I don't have any objections to the intention).

The problem is, when I search chat for specific keywords that are common in comments, I often find messages corresponding to those comments, which are often just noise in my results and hinder my searching efforts. This also occurs when I search for a given user's name to see, e.g. whenever themselves or their posts were mentioned, but if that user is also a heavy commentator on a site that uses such a bot, it creates a lot of noise in my search that I have to sift through.

Can there please be a feature to allow excluding results from specific rooms when searching chat messages, so I can exclude the rooms where the comments are being posted?

Comment: This would be nice to have!  If only SE were still working on their chat software.